# MySQL to Solr import

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene

I want to index my MySQL db table with solr.
I can see the result fetched for query on my `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/dataimport.jsp?handler=/dataimport` page, but I am getting these errors on server side for each row fetched:

```
WARNING: Error creating document : SolrInputDocument[{eno=eno(1.0)={3}, ename=ename(1.0)={pravin}, sal=sal(1.0)={300}}]
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Document [null] missing required field: id
```

This is my dataconfig.xml:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="pravindb" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pravindb" user="root" password="root" batchSize="-1" />
    <document>
        <entity name="ename" dataSource="pravindb" pk="eno" query="select* from emp">
            <field column="eno" name="eno"/> 
            <field column="ename" name="ename"/> <field column="sal" name="sal"/> 
        </entity>
     </document>
</dataConfig>
```

This is the code I have added to schema.xml:

```
<fields>
    <field name="eno" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="ename" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="sal" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>eno</uniqueKey>
<defaultSearchField>ename</defaultSearchField>
```

This is my request handler in solrconfig.xml:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">d:\clg/Project/Workspace/TestSolr/solr/conf/my-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: Please add the contents of your schema and DIH config file to your question.

Comment: Have you solved? Was my answer helpful? Do you need more help?

Comment: This is dataconfig.xml
<dataConfig>
<dataSource name="pravindb" 
 driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pravindb" 
 user="root" 
 password="root" 
 batchSize="-1" />
 <document>
<entity name="ename" dataSource="pravindb" pk="eno" 
query="select* from emp">
 
  <field column="eno" name="eno"/>
     <field column="ename" name="ename"/>
      <field column="sal" name="sal"/>
  
</entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>

Comment: this is the code that i have added to schema.xml
<fields>
  <field name="eno" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
  <field name="ename" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
       <field name="sal" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
  
 </fields>
 <uniqueKey>eno</uniqueKey>
 <defaultSearchField>ename</defaultSearchField>

Comment: this is my request handler in solrconfig.xml                            
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
      <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="config">d:\clg/Project/Workspace/TestSolr/solr/conf/my-data-config.xml</str>
      </lst>
</requestHandler>

Comment: You can update your question with the detail you added as comments. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error says the document you're trying to add through the `DataImportHandler` doesn't contain the `id` field, which is required. Your query doesn't return an id column, or you're not mapping it correctly within your import handler configuration.

**UPDATE**
From the configuration you've added, looks like your `eno` field is the uniqueKey, which should work as long as your `select *` always returns it.
The problem here is that you have more required fields in your schema that I guess you don't need. The error says you have the `id` field configured as required: you should remove it from your schema or make it optional if you need it for other purposes.

Comment: thank you very much sir.. now i have overcomed the above error. Now when i do full import of my database it shows the relevant numbers of rows fetched and "Indexing completed. Added: 8 documents."            but hen i search anything that was part of my database in QueryString it does not finds any result. can you tell me whats the problem

Comment: @user1208634 Well, the commit happens automatically given your configuration. How do you search? Can you try `q=*:*`?